# Как администрировать проект на Ubuntu (VPS)?

Tags: linux, mongodb, express

Всем привет!
Есть проект на стеке express / mongo / react, стоит на VPS (Ubuntu).
Проект предполагает нагрузку в пару тысяч пользователей с дальнейшем масштабированием.

Интересует как правильно (и удобно, не через консоль) администрировать его, а конкретно:

1. Как следить за тачкой (процессы \ память \ ram) и т.д?
   Ставил cockpit, но он ест многовато ресурсов на тачке
2. Как удалённо администрировать MongoDB?
   Открывать доступ из вне и подключаться через Compass? (не опасно ради этого открывать?)
3. На какие характеристики у железа больше обращать внимания?
   Подходит ли вообще VPS для таких проектов или лучше что-то другое

Буду рад любым советам и мнениям, спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. старый добрый zabbix кушает [всего ничего](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/5.0/en/manual/installation/requirements), но лучше под мониторинг выделить отдельный хост и собирать инфу через агент
2. подключайся через ssh
3. на все: проц, память, диск. Особенно на диск и проц так как они разделенны с другими виртуальными машинами

Comment: А можно поинтересоваться, "всего ничего" это сколько чуть более конкретно? (хочу сравнить со своей установкой Prometheus)

Comment: Я ставил в 512 оперативки на одном ядре. Памяти хватало с запасом, процессор на 10% не более в период сбора.

Comment: Zabbix requires both physical and disk memory. 128 MB of physical memory and 256 MB of free disk space could be a good starting point.

Comment: Хм, у меня Prometheus сам по себе кушает 96 МБ (но пачка разных мелких exporter'ов добавляют в сумме ещё 110 МБ и Gafana ещё 54 МБ... Наверно надо будет когда-нибудь всё-таки все exporter'ы на Rust переписать, а то чего они офигевшие такие)

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!